# How to buy something from the Mann Co. Store

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

To expand your backpack in Team Fortress 2, you can buy an item from the Mann Co. Store.

When you didn't buy something there before and your backpack gets full, you get a message stating that which has a button saying "Upgrade". I pressed that button and then was taken to a store where I bought a cosmetics item. The email Steam sent me after I bought the item is titled "Thank you for your Community Market purchase". My backpack wasn't expanded.

Apparently, it didn't buy the item from the Mann Co. Store but from the Community Market (which apparently is a different thing).

From [this wiki page](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Account_types) I now know that there is yet another store, namely the Mann Co. Online Store.

How do I make sure I buy something from the Mann Co. Store? The wiki page I linked to contains a video. What's shown in it look pretty much like what I did.

Comment: How long ago did things happen?

Comment: Did you watch [this video about upgrading your account](https://youtu.be/UhOH0wbHyoM)?

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy Happened on 2017-04-09. I didn't have much time to play since so I didn't post my question for a few weeks.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy Yes. I even mentioned that video in my question. (Last paragraph.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you go into the game, Press: Mann Co. Store. You can buy lots of cosmetics there, To make sure you buy nothing of the Market, look for stuff such as: Buy in market or Price in market. If it doesn't have a "Price in market", or anything similiar, you can't buy it in the market. So then you can buy it from the official Mann Co. Store.

Comment: I now bought a weapon (Rescue Ranger) and made sure it's 1.90 € because I found this price in [this price list](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Mann_Co_Store_Pricelist). I don't know where I was supposed to see "Buy in market" or "Price in market" but when you check out (before paying), the list contains the premium account for 0.00 € (or whatever currency you're using, I suppose). So that's how you can make sure you buy it off the Mann Co. Store.

Comment: One way to confirm what you're buying will upgrade your account is that the final purchase should include a Mann Co. hat and a "premium account" item.